# Comma separated value to columns in Excel

Tags: excel

I have multiple comma separated rows in excel with drugs name
e.g.

1) drug1,drug2,drug3,drug4

2) drug1,drug2,drug3,drug5

3) drug1,drug2,drug5,drug6

What I want to do is make these rows column such that all these rows distinct values becomes column. So in our case drug1,drug2,drug3,drug4,drug5,drug6 will become column and in rows they should have 0 if that row doesn't have that drug and 1 if it has that drug in that row.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: I know of no single way to do this but a few short steps can get you there. use data-->text to columns.  then copy the values of each column into a single column. then pivot on that column

Comment: @xQbert My single row is composed of multiple columns which is creating a problem as it gives me error 'the range can be many rows tall but no more than one column wide'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a screenshot of how I would do it in multiple steps.

1. split the data text to columns (data menu, text to columns)
2. copy data into a single column (B) (copy range B2:E4) into B10, then copy out of C10-End of range and put back into B13 etc) (and have 2 columns one for rowID and one for value
3. For rows 10,11,12 manually 1-3.  copy and paste using ctrl-down arrow to fill in each series until all filled in .
4. generate pivot Table (layout included now.)

[image]

This is assumign this is a one time thing and throw away.  If this has to be done repeatedly I'd macro it.

Comment: Can you please specify steps?